# Ubuntu 18.10 - internet stops working

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu Machines.  I was trying to do installation of Kubernetes Cluster(Master & Node) on two Ubuntu Machines.  However, while setting up networking, my internet connection stops working on both the machines.
I am doing following steps:
1) Adding IP addresses of both the machines to etc/hosts file
2)  making IP addresses static by adding following lines to
 /etc/network/interfaces file

```
        auto enp0s3
        iface enp0s3 inet static
        address <ip-address of machine>
```

After doing these changes when I restart my machine, my internet stops working.

so I edit etc/resolv.conf file and
Comment all files nameserver 127.0.0.53 & after AND add following Nameservers

```
Nameserver 8.8.8.8
Nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and then do Sudo service network-manager restart and reboot my machine.  However, after running that as well internet does not
work on my machine and etc.resolv.conf file also gets re-initialized.  Can you please advise and help on this?

Tha

Comment: If you're using network manager, you are not using the traditional network setup method - ifup.

Comment: @ Journeyman Geek - Can you please advise how ifup can be used here?  Sorry bit new to networking.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally - there's *multiple* ways to configure networks (at last count 5?)and they sometimes interfere with each other.

I'd recommend *disabling* network manager if you're doing things with the more traditional network stack

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

You can re-enable it if need be.

The systemd service that manages the 'traditional' networking stack is called networking - if its a local system, and sometimes even if its not

`systemctl restart networking` will restart it.

That should sort out your networking issues.

If resolve.conf is not respected, check if `systemd-resolved` is running, in some cases it gets in the way.